# Export excel file with php keeping html tags

Tags: php, phpexcel, export-to-excel

Hy guys.

My client wanted and option to **import** / **export** an excel file full of products.
In this excel file i have a cell which contains the product description. The import works just fine.

When he imports the excel **the description cell contains html tags** to: so an example would be:

```
<h1>Some title about the product</h1>
<p>Some text about the product <img src="absolute-path"/> also maybe a link</p>
```

My problem is when i want to export this excel with this description field, the html tags are being rendered, and i don't want that.

**Is there a way to escape the rendering and keep the the tags also,** like the code above?

Comment: You do realise that html tags have absolutely no special meaning whatsoever in MS Excel.... are you actually using PHPExcel to do your export? If so, you'll need to convert those html tags to cell styles

Comment: @MarkBaker of course i realize that, still when i open the exported excel file the description cell doesn't contain html tags, in fact its rendered. I use http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs this package

Comment: How do you mean `its rendered`..... do you mean that you actually see the markup after importing? Or are you exporting and it automagically turns your markup into valid MS Excel cell styling.... what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @MarkBaker never mind, solved it, with htmlspecialchars(). But just to be clear, if i didnt use htmlspecialchars() then in the description filed a word inside a strong tag would be bold and i couldnt see the html strong tag, with this function the word isn't bold and i see the html tag

Answer (score 1):

`htmlspecialchars()` solved my problem